# Disappearing Input submit button using css

Tags: html, css

I have an input submit button with with following code in it

```
<input class="buttons" type="button" onclick="javascript:jQuery(xxxx)" style="font-size: 12px;" value="Invite to Bid">
```

The following is the css function that put an elegant "Go" image over the Button

```
.buttons {
background: url("/images/default/product/go_bt.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

But now both image and button graphics is shown
Right now,in order to blank the value I have used the following css code

```
 input.buttons {
color: transparent;
}
```

But still the input button graphics is not disappearing, only its value has gone.. Is there any possibility to disappear this input button graphics using class-buttons in css, so that I can have just the function with "go" image...

Comment: have you tried `.buttons{border:none;}`?

Comment: If you do not want a input button to appear and only GO image should appear, use a div or span tag and apply GO image background to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so not sure whether you want to make the input disappear or remove the image.

Using css to remove a background image is

```
background-image:none
```

To make something disappear is:

```
display: none  or visibility:hidden
```

What you did below is affect the font color

```
color: transparent;
```

Ps. css has id's and classes no functions. this question also should not have been tagged with css3

Answer (score 0):

As per i understand you have to define `text-indent` for this. write like this:

```
 input.buttons {
  text-indent:-9999px
}
```